# Design issue with template map with takes different structures

Tags: c++, dictionary, templates

## Problem Description and Question

I have a `template` class `Class1`. It contains in `map` in which I want to insert structures `A` or `B`.

The problem is that the structures `A` and `B` have different types of member variables. Structure `A` has an `std::string` member variable whereas structure `B` has an `int` member variable.

The comparator is based on structure `A`. So obviously when I want to insert a structure B it will not compile.

```
Class1<B,B> c2;
c2.AddElement({1},{1});
```

How can I fix that design Issue? For instance is it possible to keep `Class1` as `template` class and do something to `TestCompare`?

**I also have a constraint.** I cannot modify the structures `A` and `B`. they are written in C code. I have no right to change them because they are external codes used by other users. I just simplified the code as much as possible.

---

## Source Code

The code was compiled on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

typedef struct {
    std::string a;
} A;

typedef struct {
    int b;
} B;


template<typename T1, typename T2> class Class1 {
    public :
      struct TestCompare {
         bool operator()(const T1 & lhs, const T1 & rhs) const {
        return lhs.a < rhs.a;
         }
       };
       Class1() {}
       ~Class1() {}
       void AddElement(const T1 & key, const T2 & value) {
          m.emplace(key, value);
        }
    private :
     std::map<T1,T2,TestCompare> m;
};

int main()
{
  Class1<A,A> c1;
  c1.AddElement({"1"},{"1"});
  
  // Problem here. Obviously it will not compile because the Operator is using 
  // the member variable of struct A.
  //Class1<B,B> c2;
  //c2.AddElement({1},{1});
  //return 0;
}
```

---

## New Source code

```
 // Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

typedef struct {
    std::string a;
} A;

typedef struct {
    int b;
} B;


bool operator<(const A & lhs, const A & rhs) {
    return lhs.a < rhs.a;
}

bool operator<(const B & lhs, const B & rhs) {
    return lhs.b < rhs.b;
}

template<typename T1, typename T2> class Class1 {
    public :
    Class1() {}
    ~Class1() {}
    void AddElement(const T1 & key, const T2 value) {
        m.emplace(key, value);
    }
    
     std::map<T1,T2> getMap() {
        return m;
    }
    
    private :
     std::map<T1,T2> m;
};

int main()
{
  Class1<A,A> c1;
  c1.AddElement({"1"},{"1"});
  
  // Problem here. Obviously it will not compile because the Operator is using 
  // the member variable of struct A.
  Class1<B,B> c2;
  c2.AddElement({1},{1});
  c2.AddElement({2},{2});
  
  for(const auto &e: c2.getMap()) {
      std::cout << e.first.b << " " << e.first.b << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've never used it but I think it's a case for https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any

Comment: Out of curiosity, how can `A` be written in C and yet have `A.a` as a `std::string`?

Comment: @PiCTo sorry The structues actually contains char * a, It's just i've written them in c++. you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could remove `TestCompare` from `Class1` and template that.

```
template<typename T> struct TestCompare {
    bool operator()(const T & lhs, const T & rhs) const {
        // default implementation
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2> class Class1 {
     ...
    private :
     std::map<T1,T2,TestCompare<T1>> m;
}
```

You could then specialise `TestCompare` for `A` and `B`

```
template<> struct TestCompare<A> {
    bool operator()(const A & lhs, const A & rhs) const {
        return lhs.a < rhs.a;
    }
};

template<> struct TestCompare<B> {
    bool operator()(const B & lhs, const B & rhs) const {
        return lhs.b < rhs.b;
    }
};
```

EDIT:
Actually you could just use `std::less` instead of `TestCompare`. It amounts to pretty much the same thing, and `std::map` uses `std::less` by default.

Comment: So @john This way I don't have to add a third template parameter right? I'll post the edit in the answer

Comment: @HaniGotc If this approach is the way you'd like to go then consider using `std::less` and drop `TestCompare`

Comment: I overloaded the operator < do you agree with the new implementation?

Comment: @HaniGotc Yes that's another way to do it. std::map uses std::less which uses operator< (all by default). I guess the decision depends on how universal you want to make the comparison you have implemented. By overloading operator< anyone can compare A and B objects anywhere. That may be a good thing or a bad thing depending on circumstances. Incidentally if you do overload operator< you should problably overload the other comparison operators. std::map uses operator< only, but it's going to be a bit strange when your users find that `a1 < a2` compiles but `a2 > a1` does not.

Answer (score 1):

`TestCompare` requires that every type you use must have a member `a` that can be compared using `<`. That's a lot of requirements, which implies a terrible design. Add a 3rd template parameter that will be used to pass a function or a functor that compares the objects

```
struct CompareA {
    bool operator()(A const & lhs, A const & rhs) const {
        return lhs.a < rhs.a;
    }
};

struct CompareB {
   bool operator()(B const& lhs, B const& rhs) const {
       /*...*/
   }
};

template<typename KeyT, typename ValueT, typename Compare> class Dict {
    public :
       Class1() {}
       ~Class1() {}
       void AddElement(KeyT const & key, ValueT const & value) {
          m.emplace(key, value);
       }
    private :
       std::map<KeyT, ValueT, Compare> m;
};

Dict<A, B, CompareA> dictA;
Dict<B, B CompareB> dictB;
```

You could specialize the struct `TestCompare`, like john has suggested in his answer, and provide it as the default template argument

```
template<typename KeyT, typename ValueT, typename Compare = TestCompare<KeyT>> class Dict { /*...*/ };
```

Such solution will allow you to provide only 2 arguments, like so

```
Dict<B, B> dict;
```

while still maintaining the ability to provide another comparer if necessary.

Comment: excuse my question. an external user will have to creater the comparator before using the class right?

Comment: Yes, but this gives you more flexibility than using specializations because the class can be used with any types. You could make the third parameter optional by providing a default argument, e.g. `TestCompare` with its specializations and still maintain the ability to provide another comparator if needed.